# PHP class: how to a make method's data to become the class properties?

Tags: php, class, oop, properties

How can I turn the **data** from a class **method** into the **properties** of that class? Is it possible?

For instance, the `article` below class only has **one property** - $var1,

```
class article
{
    public $var1 = "var 1";
    public function __construct() 
    {

    }

    public function getRow() 
    {
        $array = array(
            "article_id" => 1,
            "url"       => "home",
            "title"     => "Home",
            "content"   => "bla bla"
        );

        return (object)$array;
    }
}
```

To get $this properties,

```
$article = new article();
print_r($article->var1); // var 1
```

To get $this method,

```
$row = $article->getRow();
```

To get $this method's data,

```
print_r($row->title); // Home
```

It works fine in that way, but how if I want to **make/ move this dat**a below to the **class's properties**,

```
            "article_id" => 1,
            "url"       => "home",
            "title"     => "Home",
            "content"   => "bla bla"
```

So I can just call the data like this,

```
$article = new article();
print_r($article->title); // Home
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the magic `__set()` method to create properties that do not exists. Afterwards move the object return from the method to simple property assignation

```
class article

{
    public $var1 = "var 1";
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->getRow();
    }

    public function getRow() 
    {
        $this->article_id = 1;
        $this->url = 'home';
        $this->title = "Home";
        $this->content = 'bla bla';
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
}

$article = new article();
echo $article->title; // prints Home
```

---

If you want to save your current logic (you said move, but to be sure, you don't want to break your `getRow()` logic), you can move the assignation in another method (or in the constructor).

```
class article

{
    public $var1 = "var 1";
    public function __construct() 
    {
        foreach ($this->getRow() as $name => $value) {
            $this->$name = $value;
        }
    }
```

---

Also if you don't won't anything different that the properties from `getRow()` to be magically used, you can unset any other assignation in your `__set()` method:

```
$rows = (array)$this->getRow();
if (!array_key_exists($name, $rows)) {
    unset($this->$name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of possible way is to set this properties like this:

```
class article
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $array = array(
            "article_id" => 1,
            "url"       => "home",
            "title"     => "Home",
            "content"   => "bla bla"
        );
     foreach($array as $key => $value){
        $this->{$key} = $value;
      }
   }
}
```

And now you can get :

```
$article = new article();
print_r($article->title);  //Home
```